# install Alcatraz for Xcode 7.3.1,but prompt an error：curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806

Tags: ios, xcode, alcatraz

I install Alcatraz using the following command in terminal:

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/deploy/Scripts/install.sh | sh
```

I get an error:

> curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806

Xcode's Version is 7.3.1; before this, I have not installed Alcatraz.

[image]

Comment: Could be due to the ISP / firewalls in China. See https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/issues/445, https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/issues/428, https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/issues/334. Not much we can do on our side unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then try these commands:

```
brew remove git
brew remove curl

brew install openssl
brew install --with-openssl curl
brew install --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl git
```